# More than one INSERT STATEMENTS

Tags: sql, insert

I have a database with 3 tables. All tables have the same structure. I want to copy the records from the one table to the other 2 by using one query. Is that possible?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah that's not very hard:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (column1, colum2)
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table2;
```

You do in fact need 2 queries though, since you can only insert into 1 table with an insert statement.

Comment: Thank you for answering! I want to copy from the one table to the other two at the same time by using only one query.

Comment: You might be able to do this with an updatable view, but I think that's highly impractical. It also depends heavily on your DBMS which views are updatable.

Comment: I am using Access 2013.